# Number of linearly independent 5-tuples of vectors over a finite field with 7 elements

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

What is the number of linearly independent 5-tuples in $\mathbb{F}_7[X]_{<7}$ 
?

The <7 menas all polynomials of degree <7 with coefficients from $\mathbb{F}_7$.

I found the formula:

> $$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(q^n-q^i)$$
>   n=n-tuples, q=number of elements of the finite field

But I am not sure if I can use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a field with $q < \infty$ elements. Let $V \cong \mathbf{F}^n$ be an $n$-dimensional $\mathbf{F}$-vector space (so $|V| = q^n$). If I want to construct a $k$-tuple of linearly independent vectors in $V$ then I proceed as follows:

- Choose any nonzero vector $v_1 \in V$ ($q^n - 1$ choices)
- Choose any vector $v_2$ which is not a multiple of $v_1$ (there are $q = |\mathbf{F}|$ multiples so $q^n - q$ choices)
- At the $i$-th step, choose a vector $v_i$ which is not in the span of $v_1,\dots,v_{i-1}$ (since every element in that span can be written **uniquely* as a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_{i-1}$ there are $q^n - q^{i - 1}$ choices for $v_i$)

Thus the total is

$$ \prod_{i = 1}^k (q^n - q^{i - 1}) = \prod_{i = 0}^{k-1} (q^n - q^i). $$

Now substitute $q = 7$, $n = 7$ and $k = 5$ to get

$$ \prod_{i = 0}^{4} (7^7 - 7^i). $$

You can simplify this to an integer if you wish but this form is more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you!! That helped a lot

Comment: isnt this the same as counting the order of the linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{F})$?

Comment: @vidyarthi Not quite, because $n \ne k$ (the matrix isn't square) but yes when $n = k$.